# Pass object from parent view to sub view in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, mvvm, communication

I am currently trying to get into WPF and MVVM, but I recently ran into a problem I don't know how to solve. I am new to this, so if something is not as it should be, please tell me.

I have a ParentView with its ParentViewModel. The ParentView holds two views SubViewA and SubViewB which both have their own ViewModels. This is my ParentView.xaml:

```
<local:ViewBase.DataContext>
    <local:ParentViewModel x:Name="Model" />
</local:ViewBase.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <local:SubViewA Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Model, Path=SubViewAVisibility}" />
    <local:SubViewB Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Model, Path=SubViewBVisibility}" />
</Grid>
```

What I want to do: SubViewModelB has a property that is binded to SubViewB. I want to change that property when a certain event occurs in the ParentViewModel. I suppose this should be done by binding the property in SubViewModelB to a property in ParentViewModel, but I'm not really sure how? I tried something like the following in the ParentView.xaml:

```
<local:SubViewB Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Model, Path=SubViewBVisibility}" SomeProperty="{Binding ElementName=Model, Path=WhatIWantThePropertyToBe}" />
```

but that got me nowhere. 
So how do I solve this? I know I could do it via messaging in the MVVM light toolkit, but that seems kind of inappropiate for what I am trying to do. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a good solution to this the [EventAggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) pattern. There are some great implementations out there such as that provided by [Microsoft Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) or [TinyMessenger](http://www.grumpydev.com/2010/03/22/announcing-tinymessenger/) (very lightweight)

As a code example you would do something like this (using Prism, untested code)

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

    public ParentViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
       this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    public void PublishSomeEvent()
    {
        // When a condition occurs, publish an event any subscribers 
        // that may be listening
        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<SomeEvent>()
            .Publish(new SomeEvent("Hello World!")));
    }
}

public class SubViewModel
{
    private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

    public SubViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
       eventAggregator.GetEvent<SomeEvent>.SomeEvent(OnSomeEventOccurred);
    }

    public void OnSomeEventOccurred(SomeEvent arg)
    {
        // This method called when ParentViewModel publishes the event
        Console.WriteLine(arg.OptionalMessage);
    }
}
```

You would need a separate declaration of the event. For instance, I use this

```
public SomeEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<SomeEvent>
{
    public SomeEvent(string optionalMessage)
    {
        this.optionalMessage = optionalMessage;
    }

    public string OptionalMessage { get { return optionalMessage; } } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess I can do it that way, but is this really the correct way of doing it? It seems to be a very decoupled solution for a problem that is actually coupled. For example if I had multiple ParentViews and each had its own SubViews, this solution wouldn't work, would it? I only have one ParentView, though, so I guess this should be fine :-) Thank you!

Comment: This is the way to go. Just because they are SubViews doesn't mean they need to know about their ParentView.

For multiple ParentViews, you could have the ParentView pass a Guid or some sort of identifier to it's SubViews that is also passed as part of the fired event. Then all they need to do is check that identifier to see if the fired event is for them.

Comment: Cheers Chris :) Yep Mario event aggregator/broker is a fantastic pattern. Combined with Dependency Injection it really makes life easy. If you just want lightweight I would go with TinyMessenger. Its a single cs file and I've use it successfully in production systems

Comment: Alright, if this is best practice than I will go with it :-) Already using the MVVM light messenger system somewhere else in the application, so it's easy to implement as well ;-) Thank you guys for the quick responses

Comment: @MarioEmantsal the other thing you can try is a MultiBinding but I wouldn't recommend too many Xaml hacks to get your app to work visually. Better to be explicit in code and stick some unit tests around it. Another way would be to extract a class called VisibilityManager and inject as dependency (via interface) into both viewmodels to handle inter-viewmodel visibility based on logic/conditions

Answer (score 1):

You would have instance of `SubViewModel` in your `ParentViewModel` right? If you do then you can simply catch the event in `ParentViewModel` and manually change the particular property value of `SubViewModel`.

I am not sure whether this is the perfect way or not but this should do the work.

Another way could be to directly bind the property of SubView with property in ParentViewModel

Try something like this

```
Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ParentViewModelProperty}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately no, I do not have direct access to the SubViewModel. My Views create their Model themselves. I thought this is the appropiate way in MVVM and also it seems to be the only way where there is a clear relationship between a view and its viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks. Went for the Messenger approach, but still helpful.